# python 3.3 -- add element to an existing variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

This should be simple for many of you ... I am a beginner.

`myvariable = [35, 34, 53, 53, 64,]`

I want to add the 'number 2' to myvariable. In short i want to make my output to look like this

`myvariable = [352, 342, 532, 532, 642,]`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list elements are integers, something like this will work.

```
myvariable = [x * 10 + 2 for x in myvariable]
```

Comment: This does make assumptions about the value. It's hard to tell what the asker wants from the question, but negative values, for example, would not work in the sense of appending a two with this method. In all likelihood that doesn't matter for the poster's case, but just worth noting.